# How to get the drop shadow for a pgfplots legend right?

Tags: pgfplots, legend

When using drop shadows in `legend style` of a plot created with `pgfplots` not only the legend box but also the lines that are part of the legend images "cast a shadow" in the final picture. Since markers that are part of the legend images don't "cast a shadow" I'd say that this is not the intended behavior. Is there a way to get rid of the line shadows within the legend box?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  small,
  legend style={
    rounded corners=3pt, legend pos=north west,
    drop shadow={fill=black, opacity=0.5, shadow xshift=2pt, shadow
      yshift=-2pt}
    }
    ]
  \addplot[thick, blue]{x};
  \addplot[thick, red]{2*x};
  \legend{$x$,$2x$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem, I think, lies in the fact that the shadow is automatically inherited by the legend images.

To cope with that, it is possible to exploit the `late options` like `append after command`.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,png]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,shadows.blur}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  small,
  legend pos=north west,
  legend style={rounded corners=3pt,
    append after command={
    \pgfextra{
      \draw[rounded corners=3pt,
      drop shadow={fill=black, opacity=0.5, shadow xshift=2pt, shadow yshift=-2pt}]
        (\tikzlastnode.south west)rectangle(\tikzlastnode.north east);
      }
      }
  },
  ]
  \addplot[thick, blue]{x};
  \addplot[thick, red]{2*x};
  \legend{$x$,$2x$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

> **Code improvement**

In order to have a more automatic way to apply a shadow to the legend, here are a bunch of keys/styles; they permit to specify:

- the `legend path options` like `rounded corners` or any other option that applies to a path;
- the `legend shadow options`, namely the specific options that concern only the shadow
- the `use legend shadowed` that is simply a shortcut for the piece of code:

```
      append after command={
        \pgfextra{
          \draw[rounded corners=3pt,
          drop shadow={fill=black, opacity=0.5, shadow xshift=2pt, shadow yshift=-2pt}]
            (\tikzlastnode.south west)rectangle(\tikzlastnode.north east);
          }
       }
```

The previous MWE, now becomes:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,png,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}


\tikzset{
  legend shadow/.style 2 args={% #1 path options, #2 shadow options 
  append after command={
    \pgfextra{
      \draw[#1,drop shadow={#2}] 
       (\tikzlastnode.south west)rectangle(\tikzlastnode.north east);
      }
    }
  },
  use legend shadowed/.style={legend shadow={path options}{shadow options}},
  path options/.style={},
  shadow options/.style={},
  legend path options/.code={
    \tikzset{path options/.append style={#1}}
  },
  legend shadow options/.code={
    \tikzset{shadow options/.append style={#1}}
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  legend path options={rounded corners=3pt},
  legend shadow options={black,
    opacity=0.5,
    shadow xshift=2pt, 
    shadow yshift=-2pt
  }
]
\begin{axis}[
  small,
  legend pos=north west,
  legend style={rounded corners=3pt,
    use legend shadowed,
  },
  legend entries={$x$,$2x$} 
  ]
  \addplot[thick, blue,mark=*]{x};
  \addplot[thick, red]{2*x};
  \legend{$x$,$2x$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

#### Disclaimer

The keys `legend path options` and `legend shadow options`, for simplicity, have been put under the path `/tikz/`. This means that they *can not* be used within `legend style` like:

```
\begin{axis}[
  small,
  legend pos=north west,
  legend style={rounded corners=3pt,
    use legend shadowed,
    legend path options={rounded corners=3pt},
    legend shadow options={black,
      opacity=0.5,
      shadow xshift=2pt, 
      shadow yshift=-2pt
    }
  },
  legend entries={$x$,$2x$} 
  ]
```

Comment: Nice. Learned something new again :)

Comment: @Philipp: you're welcome :)